# Absolute and conditional convergence of a series with $\sin$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \sin^4{n}}{\sqrt{n\ln{(n)} }}$$
I can't imagine how to approach to this problem. Could you give any tips?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: @Aforest: What conditions on $a_n$ are needed to apply the AST to $\sum (-1)^n a_n$?

Comment: You're right..here $a_n$ isn't monotonic

Comment: You already posted many questions that can be solved through Dirichlet's test. Maybe, it is a good time to study it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply the alternating series test or Dirichlet test directly because $\sin^4 n / \sqrt{n \ln n}$ is not monotonically decreasing.

First, note that

$$\sin^4 n = \frac{3}{8} - \frac{\cos 2n}{2} + \frac{\cos 4n}{8}.$$

Then consider the sum of three separate series.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin^4 n}{\sqrt{n \ln n}}= \frac{3}{8}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n \ln n}} -   \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cos 2n}{\sqrt{n \ln n}} + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cos 4n}{\sqrt{n \ln n}}. $$

Each of the three series on the RHS converge by the Dirichlet test and, hence, the original series converges. This follows since $1/\sqrt{n \ln n}$ converges monotonically to $0$ and we can show that the numerators have bounded partial sums.

This is obvious for the first series, since

$$\left|\sum_{n=2}^{m}(-1)^n\right| \leqslant 1$$

More work is needed for the remaining two series.

For example, $(-1)^n \cos 2n = \cos \pi n \cos 2n = \cos (\pi -2)n, $ and

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \cos nx =\frac{\sin(mx/2)\cos[(m+1)x/2]}{\sin(x/2)}.$$

The series fails to converge absolutely.  Note that

$$\sqrt{n \ln n} \leqslant n \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \ln n}} \geqslant \frac{1}{n},$$

and

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin^4 n}{\sqrt{n \ln n}} \geqslant \frac{3}{8}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n} -   \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos 2n}{n} + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{ \cos 4n}{n}. $$

The first series on the RHS is a divergent harmonic series and the other two converge by the Dirichlet test. Hence the series on the LHS diverges and the original series converges conditionally.